# How to stop facebook app photo uploads grouping together

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, node.js

I need to upload photos via my app, but don't like that facebook is auto-grouping them together. How can I turn that off/circumvent this?

Cheers girls and guys!

More info: I'm using the Javascript facebook library.

As requested here is my current implementation, not that it will help I'm afraid, as this behaviour happens no matter how I seem to POST my data.
request

```
request = require('request');
fs= require('fs');
r = request.post('https://graph.facebook.com/photos?access_token='+access_token,  requestCallback);

form = r.form();

form.append('message', data);

form.append("image", fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path));

function requestCallback(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some snipped of your code about how are you trying to archive this?